# Jetpack Compose: Why initially loaded data is reloaded after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Minimal reproducable example, so that after screen rotation the shown random value changed :

```
package composesandbox

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.util.*

val rnd = Random()

suspend fun loadRandomNumber(): Int {
    delay(1000L) //emulating network delay
    return rnd.nextInt(1000)
}

class RandomNumberViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val num = mutableStateOf(0)

    fun reload() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            num.value = loadRandomNumber()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RandomNumberScreen() {
    val vm = viewModel<RandomNumberViewModel>()

    Column {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            vm.reload()
        }
        Text(text = "Random Number:\n ${vm.num.value}")
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            RandomNumberScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

I want the data (viewmodel.num) to be only loaded **ONCE** despite the screen rotations. Please explain, why data is reloaded on rotations.

Comment: If you only want the data loaded once, why aren't you loading it in your ViewModel's `init`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, the shortest explaination is that in real example I should use `id` of some entity to load. And on ViewModel's `init` this `id` is not yet known [it is passed as an argument for @Composable fun EntityScreen(id: Int)]

Comment: If you are using Navigation Compose and arguments there, then those arguments **are** passed to your ViewModel at construction time via the `SavedStateHandle`. Are you using Navigation Compose?

Comment: Thanks, Ian, I missed that when reading docs! That solves the problem - data could be loaded in ViewModel.init(args)

Answer (score 2):

On a screen rotation `onCreate` gets called again.

This means everything inside the Activity is recomposed.

On Recompose your Composed function `RandomNumberScreen()` is called again and this calls your `reload()` function again, which changes the value of num.

Keep in mind, that on a recompose the whole Composable gets executed again to keep the State up to date.

Your intention might be, that everythime `num` changes, the Composable should recompose. You should not trigger a function on recompose which changes `num` again.

You could use something like a variable in the viewmodel to make sure `num` is initialized and doesn't change when initialized. check if the variable is `true` or `false` before executing `reload`.

`if (!isInitialized) reload()` something like this.

Comment: Nice approach .

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are calling the reload method inside a `LaunchedEffect`, which is executed upon the first composition. When you rotate the screen, the entire screen is destroyed. All the Composables re-render themselves and hence, the inconsistent value.

Ok so you could do something like this

```
class RandomNumberViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val num = mutableStateOf(0)

    fun reload(): Int { //return something so that it can be saved
        viewModelScope.launch {
            num.value = loadRandomNumber()
        }
        return 0
    }
}

@Composable
fun RandomNumberScreen() {
    val vm = viewModel<RandomNumberViewModel>()

    Column {
        rememberSaveable {
            vm.reload()
        }
        Text(text = "Random Number:\n ${vm.num.value}")
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            RandomNumberScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note this may not be the official way of doing I could not recall anything that would help in a scenario that involves screen rotation, specifically. If anyone has a cleaner approach, please, kindly share.

Comment: That gives `    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kotlin.Unit cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry. The default implementation only supports types which can be stored inside the Bundle. Please consider implementing a custom Saver for this class and pass it to rememberSaveable().
` Further more I don't want to save the data with SavedInstanceState - I want the data to be taken from viewModel (as the data may be a Bulky list which is not fit into Bundle's size limit and can be non Parcelable or Serializable)

Comment: Oh yes, so sorry I was a bit sleepy actually. Yes the rememberSaveable won't work here but the reason is clear, i.e., why the intended behaviour is not achieved

Comment: Why not just save the value in the viewmodel instead?

Comment: I think you should change the approach.

Comment: see comment of ianhanniballake. (about loading in ViewModel.init with args)

Comment: Ok so you can do one thing

Comment: I just made the reload method return a value since `rememberSaveable` cannot save `Unit`

Comment: my problem is solved with calling reload in ViewModels constructor

Comment: Well you see your question was why, not how.